# using docker for quick switching iojs version

Tags: docker

Can be Docker used for "dockerizing" iojs or nodejs (for, for example, quick switching between them)?

And, for dockerizing any app it's not necessary to use an image of whole OS (ubuntu), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can be Docker used for "dockerizing" iojs or nodejs (for, for example, quick switching between them)?

Sure, as illustrated by the article "[Up and running with io.js and Docker](http://blog.codefresh.io/up-and-running-with-io-js-and-docker/)", based on the [iojs image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/iojs/).

> And, for dockerizing any app it's not necessary using image of whole OS (ubuntu), right?

Only if your app relies on an OS filesystem instead of relying (through static linking) on the Linux host *kernel*

For example, an application compiled in Go ([golang.org](http://golang.org/)) can run in an empty container (the [scratch container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/scratch/), see "[Building Minimal Docker Containers for Go Applications](http://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/)")

Comment: I want to use docker for develop with iojs, ruby, php (instead of using nvm, rvm and phpbrew). So, it is possible? I should create own (or take already prepared) base image and install on it necessary software?

How to create Ubuntu minimal base image by myself?

Comment: @AlexUshakov "How to create Ubuntu minimal base image by myself?": simply do a `docker search` for an image with most of what you need already included. And then do a Dockerfile from that image (as I just mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30016664/6309)