# Working on a Dockerfile in order to build a WordPress image

Tags: wordpress, debian, docker, fedora, dockerfile

I'm a newbie using Docker, and I don't understand something. If I'm using the official Dockerfile used to build the official Wordpress image, we start with:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
```

Then, to install extensions and models we have to use:

```
RUN apt-get [install or Update]
```

My question is: Why we are using `apt-get` if we are not specifying in `FROM` that our image is a Debian based distro? Could I use yum?

Comment: Note that if you want a Fedora-based wordpress image, we have a recipe for one in the [Fedora Dockerfile collection](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/wordpress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WordPress image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/f72c6758fd75fc9c4a4ca2c0baabcd92b90381b9/apache/Dockerfile) does begin with `FROM php:5.6-apache`.

But the [`php:5.6-apache` image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/1dcb6d17643e48ea1329ede9cf9a08b2f697b2fd/5.6/apache/Dockerfile) starts with `FROM debian:jessie`.
Hence the `apt-get`.

Each image builds up based on another base image.

[image: https://docs.docker.com/terms/images/docker-filesystems-multilayer.png]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check the php:5.6-apache image.